# Rspec and Declarative Authorization: Rules in dummy app doesn't work with testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, declarative-authorization

I'm trying to integration-test a gem that uses authlogic and declarative authorization. 
To check a custom controller in my dummy-app I created a new spec/dummy/config/authorization_rule.rb file:

```
authorization do
role :admin do
    has_permission_on :admin_events, :to => [:manage]
end 
end
```

When I fire up a server in test environment (rails s -e test) everything works as expected.
But when I run my tests with capybara (doesn't matter if using rack_test, selenium or webkit) the custom rules aren't loaded, my test-user is not authorized to access the controller.

Declarative Authorization's built in test-helper without_access_control does work with rack_test, but not with js=true.

Any ideas? As this is "declarative" I can't add permissions on the fly (runtime). Or is it possible anyhow?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Declarative Authorization's built in test-helper without_access_control does work with rack_test, but not with js=true ... did you find out a way round this?